# Convert Joda LocalDate to Unix Epoch Time

Tags: java, jodatime, unix-timestamp

I'm looking to convert a Joda LocalDate to unix epoch time (long) in Java.

I've looked in to the LocalDate documentation and there doesn't appear to be anything on getting this value.

[Link](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html)

I'm new to Joda and have been searching around and haven't found a right way of doing this yet. I know this has to be easy but I haven't figured it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `LocalDate#toDate()#getTime()`?

Comment: Yeah I knew it was a stupid question...you need to divide by 1000 because getTime() returns milliseconds. You can add this as an answer and note the  conversion from milliseconds to seconds.

Comment: @MadProgrammer LocalDate#toDateTime()#getMillis() keeps it entirely within Joda

Comment: @SteveChaloner What ever floats the boat :P

Answer (score 2):

In a general case it's not as simple as it seems - Unix time defines a continuous timeline starting at 1970-01-01 00:00 **UTC**. `LocalDate` is - as the name suggests - local to a certain place in the world. The beginning and end of the day 2015-01-01 is at a different point in time in Sydney than in Berlin. Also, Unix time involves *time* whereas LocalDate... not ;) So - if it indeed makes sense to convert a **Local Date** to a **UTC timestamp** there are two questions you must answer for yourself:

- in which time zone do you want to interpret the `LocalDate`?
- what should be the time part after the conversion?

Assuming it does make sense to do it and you can answer the questions, you can implement it using

```
LocalDate#toDateTime(LocalTime time, DateTimeZone zone)#getMillis()
```

or - if you want the start of the day

```
LocalDate#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone zone)#getMillis()
```